# Highlighting fields in an HTML form from controller while validating MVC ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML form with two dropdown lists that represent a credit card expiry month and year.  In my controller, I am checking to see if the month/year selected is in the future.  If not, I add an error to the ModelState to be returned to the user.

The only thing I haven't figured out is how to get the dropdown lists to highlight in red like a textbox does when it doesn't meet the required field requirements, or other checks implemented using DataAnnotations.

Any hints?  Using C# and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729440/validate-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: shawn, please share your View so we can see your way of forming your dropdownlist