# How to display a validation if dropdownlist value == null in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, validation, null

I'm having trouble in displaying validation message when a null value is selected.

My code for the dropdownlist:

```
<strong>@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })</strong>
@Html.DropDownList("Category", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I understand that String.Empty equals to a null value(Correct me if i'm wrong).

My code for my model:

```
namespace Mp.Models
{
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

  public partial class Content
  {
      [Required(ErrorMessage: "A Category is required!")]
      public string Category { get; set; }
  } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [validate a dropdownlist in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729440/validate-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Have you included the relevant `ValidationMessage()` helper? Does the html your generating include `<option value=""></option>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm populating my dropdownlist from database. I'm adding `Empty.String` so the first value displayed on the dropdownlist would be blank.

Comment: Yes I know that. Were you intending to answer my queries?

Comment: I've added `ValidationSummary()` to display the validation message, if that's what you're asking. How am i suppose to display a validation message if the first value(null) is selected?

Comment: dont use string use int

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Int? I do not understand. How do I change `Empty.String` to int?

Comment: I assume that's `@Html.ValidationSummary` and not `@ValidationSummary`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, you're right. But what about the validation for a null value?

Comment: Start by using strongly typed helpers `@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })` and `@Html.ValidationSummaryFor(m => m.Category)` where you model contains `public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }` (or alternatively you could use `ViewBag` for the `SelectList`

Comment: Refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bszsPb) for an example (select the first option and then Save)