# @Html.DropDownListFor not populating with validation element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC project in studio 2013 based on C#.

I have a number of fields on a web pags using razor syntax some of these are just regular `@Html.EditorFor()` with a class of `@class = "form-control"` and others are `@Html.DropDownListFor()`.

I have a model that has enables me to add data annotations for form validation. I am using entity framework to bring in my districts from SQL and i am displaying these as a list for the dropdown.  this all works fine, its purely an issue with displaying the validation message im having.

Please take a look at the following code sample i have used to create these.

Here is my model...

```
namespace MySystem.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CRecord_Buddy))]
    public partial class CRecord
    {

     // properties used to pull back and display the name etc instead on an   id in dropdown boxes.

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select District.")]
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }


 public class CRecord_Buddy
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Surname.")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        ...
    }
 }
```

}

my create.cshtml page looks like the following...

```
//code for Surname 
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.client.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.client.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 @Html.ValidationMessage("Surname", "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })

//code for district
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.client.District, new SelectList(Model.allDistricts, "ID", "District1", 1), "- Select District -")
 @Html.ValidationMessage("DistrictName", "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.client.District, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The below is a image of what is displayed when the validation kicks in...

[image] 
[image]

As you can see from the above images, the validation works fine for the @Html.EditorFor item but not the @Html.Dropdownlistfor item.  These are both set up the same in terms of populating the validation but i cant seem to get the dropdownlist item working properly.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729440/validate-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: What is property `District`? (all you have shown is one named `DistrictName`)

Answer (score 0):

Required attribute is on `DistrictName` not on `District`.
That's reason validation result is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define as shown below:

```
//code for district
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.client.DistrictName, new SelectList(Model.allDistricts, 
    "ID", "District1", 1), "- Select District -")
@Html.ValidationMessage("DistrictName", "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.client.DistrictName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```